# What is $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{2x^6y}{x^6+y^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Wolfram Alpha says:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{2x^6y}{x^6+y^2} = 0,$$
but provides no explanation.

Would the function even have a limit?

Comment: As the total exponent of the numerator is 7 and the maximum exponent of the denominator is 6, my instinctive answer would be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0\leq |\frac {2x^6y}{x^6+y^2}|\leq |\frac {2x^6y}{x^6}|=2|y|$. Then $|y|\to 0 $ means $|\frac {2x^6y}{x^6+y^2}|\to 0$ for $(x,y)\to (0,0)$

Answer (score 1):

For any $|x| < \delta$ and $|y| < \delta$ we have $$\left| \frac{2x^6y}{x^6 + y^2} \right| \leq \frac{2x^6|y|}{x^6 + y^2}.$$

Now consider $$\frac{2x^6}{x^6 + y^2} = \frac{2}{1 + (y^2/x^6)}.$$

This quantity is clearly bounded by $2$. Therefore,

$$\left| \frac{2x^6y}{x^6 + y^2} \right| \leq \frac{2x^6|y|}{x^6 + y^2} \leq 2|y|.$$

So we can choose $\delta = \epsilon/2$.